# Maven release plugin. Can't tag the branch

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using maven release plugin in order to tag my poject in SVN. I run Jenkins job with following maven goal:

```
-Pmake-tag release:clean release:prepare -sbuild/deploy-settings.xml -Dresume=false
```

My pom.xml

```
<profile>
            <id>make-tag</id>
            <modules>
                <module>../common-core</module>
                <module>../htdocs</module>
                <module>../deployer</module>
                <module>../configuration</module>
            </modules>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <preparationGoals>validate</preparationGoals>
                        <!--    <tagBase>svn:http://172.16.71.2:8080/repos/DMC/Copyright2/tags/</tagBase>  -->
                            <useEditMode>true</useEditMode>
                            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                            <updateWorkingCopyVersions>false</updateWorkingCopyVersions>
                            <tagNameFormat>rel-${env.REL_TAG}</tagNameFormat>
                            <username>${env.SCM_USER}</username>
                            <password>${env.SCM_PASSWD}</password>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

<build>
 ...
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/Copyright2</developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/Copyright2</connection>  
        <url>scm:svn:http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/Copyright2</url>
    </scm>
</build>
```

When I run jenkins job I got error

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username jenkins --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file C:\Windows\TEMP\maven-scm-756812364.commit --revision 51859 http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC scm:svn:http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/MyProject/tags/rel-99346"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyJob\workspace
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'scm:svn:http:\\<svn_ip>:8080\repos\DMC\MyProject\tags\rel-99346'
```

althougth in log output all slashes are \ in pom.xml url was set properly.
Will be happy to get assistance.

Comment: can you run it manually (outside of Jenkins)?

Comment: yes. I got same error

Comment: ok, so It's not Jenkins error. It is a svn and/or maven error. .... or your server URL is wrong.

Comment: Url is ok. I double check it

Comment: Are you using the same working copy you are working on with a post-commit hook?

Answer (score 0):

The commandline ends with the following: `scm:svn:http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/MyProject/tags/rel-99346`. That's wrong: svn.exe doesn't understand the scm: prefix, that's something for Maven to understand what kind of String this is. I can't see that quick where this value is coming from, maybe you can explain it yourself.
By the way, the `<scm><url>` is without scm: prefix, it points to a webURL